# Pasar valor de la cuenta de un input/textarea a un span

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero enviar el valor de la cuenta de un input a un span con el id=importe mediante javascript.

```js
document.getElementById("#importe").value=document.getElementById("#cuenta").value;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="cuenta" id="cuenta" class="form-control" value=0 placeholder="Importe del Pedido" required readonly="readonly" >

<span>Total</span>
<span id="importe">Importe del Pedido</span>
```

Comment: Elimina todas las `#` de tu código, eso es todo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El query selector `#` se usa con la funcion `querySelector`, si vas a usar `getElementByID` solo colocar el `id` nada mas. Y para elementos no `input`, se usa `innerHTML`

```js
document.getElementById("importe").innerHTML=document.getElementById("cuenta").value;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="cuenta" id="cuenta" class="form-control" value="0" placeholder="Importe del Pedido" required readonly="readonly" >

<span>Total</span>
<span id="importe">Importe del Pedido</span>
```

Comment: Otra opción es usar [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

Answer (score 0):

> Cuando usas la función `getElementById` no necesitas colocar el `#`,
>   eso solo sería necesario si usaras la función `querySelector`.

Answer (score 0):

Para colocar un valor en la etiqueta span debes hacerlo así

```
 $('#importe').html($('#cuenta').val());
```

Además tienes que crear un función o declarar un evento que te dispare esa acción